# mdadm: Resume initial sync

Tags: software-raid, raid10, md

I have a new md RAID10 that I created (*on a Synology DS416slim, which is besides the point*), which was in the process of initial sync:

```
root@ds416slim:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md2 : active raid10 sdd3[3] sdc3[2] sdb3[1] sda3[0]
      1943881088 blocks super 1.2 64K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]
      [===>.................]  resync = 19.8% (386172736/1943881088) finish=2613.6min speed=9932K/sec

md1 : active raid1 sdc2[1] sdb2[2] sda2[0] sdd2[3]
      2097088 blocks [4/4] [UUUU]

md0 : active raid1 sdc1[1] sdb1[2] sda1[0] sdd1[3]
      2490176 blocks [4/4] [UUUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Noting it's really horrible sync speed (it should've been closer to 100M than 10M), I decided to `pause` the sync using `echo idle > /sys/block/md2/md/sync_action`

After the tests (where `hdparm` showed that `/dev/sdd` had horrible performance), I tried to resume it with `echo resync > /sys/block/md2/md/sync_action`. However the sync didn't resume and stayed in idle state:

```
root@ds416slim:~# echo resync > /sys/block/md2/md/sync_action
root@ds416slim:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md2 : active raid10 sdd3[3] sdc3[2] sdb3[1] sda3[0]
      1943881088 blocks super 1.2 64K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]

md1 : active raid1 sdc2[1] sdb2[2] sda2[0] sdd2[3]
      2097088 blocks [4/4] [UUUU]

md0 : active raid1 sdc1[1] sdb1[2] sda1[0] sdd1[3]
      2490176 blocks [4/4] [UUUU]

unused devices: <none>
root@ds416slim:~# cat  /sys/block/md2/md/sync_action
idle
```

I checked on possible options on how to resume the sync as the options given in the [`sysfs` section of the MD documentation on kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/md.html#md-devices-in-sysfs) gives a list that doesn't have a `resume` option. Reading the listed options all seem to imply `resync` as the correct action, but it didn't resume the initial sync as seen above.

My questions are:

- Will this affect the raid and how?
- How do I resume the initial sync?
- Is it safe to ignore the whole thing and start using the raid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `repair` action - ie: `echo repair > /sys/block/md2/md/sync_action`

In theory you can use the array during the repair, but I would let this first-time repair/resync to finish before putting valuable data on the disks.

From [md man page:](https://linux.die.net/man/4/md)

> **md/sync_action**
>
> This can be used to monitor and control the
>   resync/recovery process of MD.  In particular, writing "check" here
>   will cause the array to read all data block and check that they are
>   consistent (e.g. parity is correct, or all mirror replicas are the
>   same).  Any discrepancies found are NOT corrected. A count of problems
>   found will be stored in md/mismatch_count. Alternately, "repair" can
>   be written which will cause the same check to be performed, but any
>   errors will be corrected. Finally, "idle" can be written to stop the
>   check/repair process.

In other words, `resync` is ignored because it is *not* an accepted action - while `check`, `repair` and `idle` are.

Comment: May I request a more verbose answer before I accept this?

Comment: @Samveen sure, I edited my answer